# Наложение кликов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два блока. Необходимо, чтобы при клике на блок №2 не срабатывало действие клика по блоку №1.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.b_1', function(event){
    var target = $(event.currentTarget);
    target.css({
      color: 'white'
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.b_2', function(event){
    var target = $(event.currentTarget);
    target.css({
      color: 'white'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.b_1, .b_2 {
  height: 40px;
  color: black;
}

.b_1 {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.b_2 {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='b_1'>1
      <div class='b_2'>2</div>
</div>
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/wk6v0o4e/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

добавьте вызов `.stopPropagation()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.b_1', function(event){
    var target = $(event.currentTarget);
    target.css({
      color: 'white'
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.b_2', function(event){
    //Чтобы событие не всплывало в объемлющий div
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    var target = $(event.currentTarget);
    target.css({
      color: 'white'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.b_1, .b_2 {
  height: 40px;
  color: black;
}

.b_1 {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.b_2 {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='b_1'>1
      <div class='b_2'>2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вариант рабочий для примера! Разбираюсь со своим кодом, у меня не работает. Возможно из-за того, что блок 1 - это тег `<a>`

Comment: так надо было так вопрос и задавать :) и от типа тэга поведение не должно измениться

Comment: Вы правы, не меняется. Но у меня по клику на ссылку разворачивается список, а по клику на блок внутри всплывает подсказка. Список раскрывается всё равно при клике на подсказку(

Comment: а разворачивание списка точно на onclick?

Comment: Да, но код скрипта, который список раскрывает писал не сам, вносил только в него необходимые дополнения. Прикрепил скрипт во внешние - https://jsfiddle.net/wk6v0o4e/3/

Comment: @Torawhite но как вы видите, код в фидлере так же рабочий. Есть явно какая-то загвоздка, которую вы упускаете. Хорошо бы понять все-таки, как начинается обработка скрипта по разворачиванию выпадающего списка

Comment: не спорю, я скрипт по раскрытию списка прикрепил во внешние скрипты - ссылка выше. Гляньте опытным глазом, если время есть, мой глаз что-то замылился

Comment: @Torawhite, это хорошо в отладчике смотреть. Насколько я понял, этот скрипт сам навешивается на `a` с подпиской на click.

Comment: @Torawhite вы пример верстки покажите вашего меню. И где ваш `a` и где ваш `div` и `ul` с меню

Comment: могу даже ссылку дать - фильтр слева, у "операционные системы", например, появляется "i" - нажимаем на неё и раскрывается подсказка и список http://store.torawhite.ru/?view=store_goods&parent=2&category=18

Comment: @Torawhite, ok. Но тогда сегодня попозже посмотрю

Comment: хорошо, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Torawhite. Такое ощущение,что у вас на диве со знаком (i) тоже висит список и именно он же и разворачивается, а не какой-то, уровнем выше. Т.е. сам div с информацией, и отрабатывает как список. Сдается мне вы куда-то не туда навесили плагин с этим меню. Надеюсь понятно описал. :) Посмотрите внимательней в DevTools.

Comment: если честно, то не совсем. У меня есть скрипт выпадающего меню сверху, он практически идентичный тому, который подсказки открывает, но они на разные классы навешаны. И почему пропадают мои обращения в начале текста через "@"?((

Comment: @Torawhite, у меня такое ощущение, что вам надо подправить верстку. Div с информацией не должен быть чилдом, а должен быть сиблингом, только спозиционированный на нужный пункт меню. Это раз. Во вторых, что должно происходить, когда кликают по диву с информацией?

Comment: по клику всё просто - добавляется класс блоку (i), а по этому классу в стилях дочернему блоку  прописано `display: block;` там у меня коряво всё с этим блоком, я его вёрсту не дописал - застопорился на том, что у меня список стал раскрываться при нажатии на (i). "чилдом" - понял (child), а "сиблингом" - не понял. А позиционировать жёстко не хочу - у меня там всё на `display: flex;` завязано

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51654/discussion-between-sublihim-and-torawhite).

Answer (score 5):

В конце функции клика блока №2 добавте, event.stopPropagation();

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.b_2', function(event){
    var target = $(event.currentTarget);
    target.css({
        color: 'white'
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! В примере работает, а у меня в коде почему-то нет... Не могу понять почему. Разница только в том, что в моём коде первый блок - это тег `<a>`